# Mais uma string com problema de tradução

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, internacionalização

A *string* padrão que fica na caixa de texto ao votar para fechar uma pergunta como "outro motivo"

[image: Caixa de texto ao votar para fechar como "outro motivo"]

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Thanks for reporting!